# Rails - no such file to load -- rdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdf

I have few ruby classes, that requires 'rdf' gem - when running them from original project everythings works ok.
I coppied those classes to my Rails project to folder Vendor/lfm and added the path to environment.rb.
The files load, but the 'rdf' gem that is used in those copied classes does not load.
I get: `no such file to load -- rdf`

and

```
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'  
vendor/lfm/rdf_transform.rb:14:in `<class:RdfTransform>'  
vendor/lfm/rdf_transform.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'  
activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
```

The RubyPlatform is set the same, and i can see the 'rdf' gem listed in libraries of Rails project.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to require this gem in your actual class files - they should instead be listed on your Gemfile, where they'll be required automatically by Rails.

Comment: Thans this, worked well. I had to run bundle install(maybe there is way to specify path to gems already in system), and then it started working.

Comment: You did the right thing - "bundle install" makes bundler use the system gem if it's already there. You only need to run that command when you change the Gemfile.